# Hosting of static content without server, only through CDN

Tags: web-hosting, cdn, static-content

My content is fully static, using only HTML, CSS, JS. It's only one page, which needs to load really fast from any country, and should be online for only 3 months.

I already have the domain name.

I just need a CDN where I would keep my HTML, CSS, JS and image files, to be served really fast in Japan, China or USA.

Do I still need to have a web server? Do CDN provider also offers simple hosting?

Comment: Check out: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/54037/20604 for your answer, for extended debate/conversations please use our chat should you have any questions on how this can be done.

Comment: Bybye, I appreciate you pointing to the big FAQ, but this does not answer my question, which is Do I need to have a web server or not.